# CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes leaves out one valid mode

Tags: macos, swift, core-graphics

When programmatically working with display modes in OS X ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/index.html)), I've found that the `CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes` leaves out the rightmost option that is presented in System Preferences.

A [simple utility](https://gist.github.com/grep-awesome/3bab57cebd7787f245b8) that prints the size of the current display mode and all available display mode sizes outputs this

```
current size: 1920x1200
available sizes:
2880x1800
1440x900
2560x1600
2048x1280
1024x768
800x600
640x480
1680x1050
1280x800
```

`1920x1200` is a valid option [image]

All of the other options that System Preferences gives are represented in the list. Does anyone have any idea why `1920x1200` may not be included? I have tried changing to another one of the pre-defined values in system prefs, but it did not cause `1920x1200` to be included.

## Edit (the accepted answer is much better than these shenanigans, but I'm leaving this info just in case)

The "scaled" display modes can be found by referencing a private API.

You can create a header file that makes the private methods available: see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/grep-awesome/18d64fc375eca7f4af7b) that I borrowed from [this project](https://github.com/robbertkl/ResolutionMenu).

Then you can see all modes, including the scaled ones like this

```swift
print("Private modes:\n")

var numDisplayModes: Int32 = 0
CGSGetNumberOfDisplayModes(mainDisplayID, &numDisplayModes)
print("Num modes \(numDisplayModes)")

for i in 0...(numDisplayModes-1) {
    var pmode: CGPrivDisplayMode = CGPrivDisplayMode()
    CGSGetDisplayModeDescriptionOfLength(mainDisplayID, CInt(i), &pmode, CInt(sizeof(CGPrivDisplayMode)))
    
    print("\t\(pmode.modeNumber): \(pmode.width)x\(pmode.height) -- \(pmode.density)  \n")
}
```

Comment: will apple approve if i use this api?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's public API that's only documented in the header. `CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes()` takes an `options` parameter, which is a dictionary. The docs (and even the headers) say that it's unused and you must pass `NULL`, but you can pass a dictionary with the key `kCGDisplayShowDuplicateLowResolutionModes` and value `kCFBooleanTrue`.

The option name is not really clear. It includes a bunch of extra modes.

Also, you may need to use `CGDisplayModeGetPixelWidth()` and `CGDisplayModeGetPixelHeight()` to distinguish between the point size and the pixel size of the backing store. (`CGDisplayModeGetWidth()` and `CGDisplayModeGetHeight()` return point size. By comparing those values, you can determine if the mode is scaled.)

Comment: i passed `kCGDisplayShowDuplicateLowResolutionModes`  with `kCFBooleanTrue` still getting few resolutions only.