# How to get all possible screen resolutions in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, screen-resolution

I want to fetch all the supported resolutions for mac screen. 
I'm using the below code for achieving all supported resolutions:

```
CFArrayRef modeList;
modeList=CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes(displays[i], NULL);
```

By using the above code, I'm only getting the resolutions as shown in below image:

[image]

I have installed one app which shows supported resolutions for my mac screen. It shows the resolutions as shown into below image. I also want to get the higher resolutions as they are showing.

[image]

I have referred the below link:
[CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes leaves out one valid mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859718/cgdisplaycopyalldisplaymodes-leaves-out-one-valid-mode)

But I don't know how to get other supported resolutions using kCGDisplayShowDuplicateLowResolutionModes.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer at the link you provide does present the answer you need, though it's using an undocumented options flag which is unfortunate.  You have to pass in the options dictionary to your call to `CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes` as it indicates:

```
CGDirectDisplayID mainDisplayID = CGMainDisplayID();
CFStringRef keys[1] = { kCGDisplayShowDuplicateLowResolutionModes };
CFBooleanRef values[1] = { kCFBooleanTrue };

CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void**) keys, (const void**) values, 1, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks );

CFArrayRef modesArray = CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes( mainDisplayID, options );
```

and then look through the returned display modes seems to work for me.  Note that you'll probably want to check the boolean returned by `CGDisplayModeIsUsableForDesktopGUI(…)` to filter out those that are invalid (depending on your use case).

Obviously you'll be passing in each of the different display ids in turn and get output more like this:

```
Display 3: external, main
points: (2560 x 1440), pixels: (2560, 1440)
points: (1280 x 720), pixels: (1280, 720)
points: (800 x 600), pixels: (800, 600)
points: (1024 x 768), pixels: (1024, 768)
points: (1280 x 960), pixels: (1280, 960)
points: (1344 x 1008), pixels: (1344, 1008)
points: (1344 x 756), pixels: (1344, 756)
points: (1600 x 1200), pixels: (1600, 1200)
points: (1600 x 900), pixels: (1600, 900)
points: (2048 x 1152), pixels: (2048, 1152)

Display 2: builtin,
points: (2880 x 1800), pixels: (2880, 1800)
points: (1440 x 900), pixels: (1440, 900)
points: (3360 x 2100), pixels: (3360, 2100)
points: (2560 x 1600), pixels: (2560, 1600)
points: (2048 x 1280), pixels: (2048, 1280)
points: (1650 x 1050), pixels: (1650, 1050)
points: (1280 x 800), pixels: (1280, 800)
points: (1152 x 720), pixels: (1152, 720)
points: (1024 x 768), pixels: (1024, 768)
points: (800 x 600), pixels: (800, 600)

Display 5: external,
points: (1920 x 1200), pixels: (1920, 1200)
points: (960 x 600), pixels: (960, 600)
points: (800 x 600), pixels: (800, 600)
points: (1024 x 768), pixels: (1024, 768)
points: (1024 x 640), pixels: (1024, 640)
points: (1280 x 960), pixels: (1280, 960)
points: (1280 x 800), pixels: (1280, 800)
points: (1344 x 1008), pixels: (1344, 1008)
points: (1344 x 840), pixels: (1344, 840)
points: (1600 x 1200), pixels: (1600, 1200)
points: (1600 x 1000), pixels: (1600, 1000)
```

Also note that these numbers don't line up with what's showing for MBP, for example.  "looks like 1920 x 1200" which doesn't match any of the listed resolutions.

---

Another dev was having trouble getting this to work, so I pushed my quick hacked together test project that works up to github so others can see the [entire working project](https://github.com/GeekAndDad/TestGetAttachedDisplayResolutions).  Hopefully that'll help someone (***DO*** clean up that code before you use it in any kind of product though - it's just a quickest possible hacked together test code).

Comment: Documentation in the header files **is** documentation. ;)

Comment: :) Yes, well, the documentation in the header file clearly says "The "options" field is reserved for future expansion; pass NULL for now."  So the flag is documented as existing, but there is no indication of what it's to be used for or that it's a valid parameter to CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes.  Hence my comment.

Comment: Ah, I missed your wink.  ;) Indeed.

Comment: @swapnil-patel if this answered your question you could accept it to let us know and to remove it from the list of Unanswered Questions on SO. If this didn't answer your question, please clarify which part isn't working for you.  Cheers!

Comment: @Dad after passing the `kCGDisplayShowDuplicateLowResolutionModes` for me still getting same resolutions(few resolutions)  .

Comment: @jarvis12 you'll probably need to post code and info about system you're on etc for me to be able to help you see what's wrong.  it works on my system with the code posted as demonstrated by the output I showed above, so something is different about your code or system, seems like.

Comment: @Dad see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650921/how-to-show-all-supported-resolutions-for-display-in-mac-app) mine is also same problem same code . i am using mac mini.

Comment: @Dad and also if use [this](https://github.com/robbertkl/ResolutionMenu/blob/master/Resolution%20Menu/DisplayModeMenuItem.m) will apple approve it .

Comment: I'm doing it a lot differently than you are.  Yours looks better in some ways, but if it doesn't work then I guess it's not.  I posted my quick test project on github and added a link to it in my answer above so it's easier to see.